# What Is The Best Way to Retrieve Measure_Data From Project_Measures in Sonarqube 5.2

Tags: sonarqube

currently I'm porting an internal SonarQube plugin from SonarQube 4.5.1 to SonarQube 5.2 because we are relying on a not yet released feature ([use any Guava version in plugins](http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6370)).

Now, I have difficulties to get data of my custom measures from the SQL table `project_measures`. In the previous version I used the class `DatabaseSession` and `MeasureModel`, but those classes are not available any more (see those commits `29ae9b385a7bf720ae89637582c862df43b7fd0d` and `183b104dadd5b350d4d00a1ef2336094755e5f4f` in the [Github repository](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube)).

Can you tell me what is now the best way to get data of custom measures. Maybe web services?

Best Regards

Schrieveslaach

#### Update:

I tried to use `org.sonar.db.DbSession` and `org.sonar.db.measure.MeasureDao` but when I install the plugin and start SonarQube I get a `ClassNotFoundException` because those classes are not loaded by the server.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Depending on your answer, you may need to use a WS to get the custom measure or use an upcoming (and not yet defined) API of the Compute Engine

Comment: I want to display a measure in a widget. Can you tell me more about that upcoming API?

Comment: I can't, this is a work in progress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thanks for testing the version 5.2 which is being under development. Note that it's far from being stable, so it is not production ready.

There are several (good) reasons why it's not possible anymore to use these classes :

- it was always recommended to not consider the database as an API, so plugins should not load data directly through DAO. This constraint is enforced since 5.2. Core classes are not accessible anymore from plugins.
- the most annoying constraint (and so the most voted JIRA ticket) was to have code analyzers connecting to database (read and write). After a few months (years?) of development, this connection was finally dropped. That's a big change. It will unlock lots of new features, for example the plugin for Github (http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/GitHub+Plugin).

That being said, the only way to extract data is using the web services. A big effort is done to implement in 5.2 most of the WS that were missing in previous versions. As an example api/custom_measures could be useful for you.

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks for your answer. I forgot to mention that I want to display the data in a widget. Is it still the best way to use a WS?

Comment: Obviously WS can't be called from Ruby code (as it's server-side technology). The solution, which will become the official way soon, is to implement a JS widget that sends ajax requests to WS. This JS code must be declared in the ruby template for now.